# UTC iso8601 date to certain format with local timezone

Tags: javascript

I have the UTC date in this format: `2015-12-09T15:44:33.737`

Currently I am doing

```
var ts = '2015-12-09T15:44:33.737'

var localTimeString = new Date(ts).toLocaleDateString() + ", " + new Date(ts).toTimeString();
```

See here: http://jsbin.com/pakoxegete/1/edit?js,console

to get `12/9/2015, 10:44:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

But the format I would like is

`12/09/2015, 10:44:33 AM EST`

The main changes I am after is ability to go from military time to standard time with AM/PM and also to be able to convert `GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` to `EST`. The time zones only have to work for the main timezones located in the USA.

Edit: I am interested in `PST, MST, CST, EST` and their daytime counter parts: `PDT, MDT, CDT, EDT`

Comment: Do not parse strings with Date.parse. Your format will be treated as local in ECMAScript 2015 hosts, UTC in ES5 hosts, and anything in earlier hosts (e.g. NaN in IE 8). Manually parse the string (use a library or simple function). The string `12/09/2015, 10:44:33 AM EST` is ambiguous for both the day/month component (12 Sep or 9 Dec?) and the time zone part (there are three EST time zones).

Comment: Typical USA format of month/day/year. I am only aware of two eastern timezones EST and EDT, but I am interested in `PST, MST, CST, EST` and their daytime counter parts: `PDT, MDT, CDT, EDT`

Comment: Unfortunately, the internet is not exclusively for the US and the vast majority of the world's population doesn't use the peculiar US format. There is no standard for time zone abbreviations, Wikipedia currently lists [*two ESTs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) but used to list 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the functions has more options that I expected. Was able to compromise and get this

```
var ts = '2015-12-09T15:44:33.737'

var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', timeZoneName: 'short' };
console.log(new Date(ts).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
```

Which results in `December 9, 2015, 10:44 AM EST`

Comment: You should try that in more than on browser. Formatting of date strings is not a part of the ECMAScript language specification. It is part of the [*EMCAScript Internationalization API*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/), but that's [*not supported by all browsers*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl).

Comment: RobG is right about browser support.  If you find yourself doing much date formatting, moment.js is worth looking into.  It's been a godsend while waiting for Intl support.

Comment: @Jack I am using moment.js currently but they dropped timezone support in favor of their new timezone script. Would it be possible to achieve the same effect I have above using moment.js only?